# Inheritance vs Composition in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Many tables have audit columns like created_by, created_date, updated_by, updated_date.

Uses Java we can create Audit class with these columns and logic.

Other entities can get Audit functionality uses:

1. Inheritance (use @MappedSuperclass for Audit class)
   or
2. Composition (add attribute with type Audit)

Which option is more correct for Audit columns?

Comment: _Is_ `User` an `Audit`, or does `User` _have_ an `Audit`?

Comment: Both variants are possible

But I think option "User have an Audit" is more correct

Answer (score 0):

In general for OOP there is this design pattern of "Composition over inheritance" but it is more functionality-oriented.

Here you model the domain.

If your entity (user) is audited - consider superclass AuditedEntity.

Can be root for all your audited entities (users, ...).

Note: Be aware, that this way you put on yourself a convention for consistent naming of audit columns in your project.

Comment: Let's check AuditedEntity and UserEntity for IS A and HAS A

UserEntity is a AuditedEntity? In general, the answer is probably No
UserEntity has a AuditEntity (Audit functionality)? The answer is rather Yes

In general, these columns may not be moved into a separate class and then all is Ok
But if they moved then we have two options...